# The resource cannot be found error when I click Log off after authentication timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I use the default authentication method provided by ASP.NET 4 SimpleMembership. I don't set the authentication timeout in web.config file, I set the timeout using the following code:

```
int timeout = model.RememberMe ? 2880 : 10; // Timeout in minutes, if rememberme is checked it's 2 days else 10 minutes
                    var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(model.UserName, model.RememberMe, timeout);
                    string encrypted = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                    var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encrypted);
                    cookie.Expires = System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeout);
                    cookie.HttpOnly = true; 
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Everything works fine, except for the Log off link that is in a shared view called _LoginPartial.cshtml and it's code is:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <text>
    Hello, @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })!
        @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
        }
    </text>
}
else
{
    <ul>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
    </ul>
}
```

Log off works fine when the timeout doesn't occur. When the authentication times out after 10 minutes and when the user clicks the Log off button, the user is redirected to the Login page with the url

```
http://localhost:11408/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fAccount%2fLogOff
```

After the user logs in, it is redirected to the url:

```
http://localhost:11408/Account/LogOff
```

And the following error occurs:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Account/LogOff
```

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and I am not sure how to handle it. The following is my route config:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

How do I resolve this? :O

Comment: Is your `LogOff` action method or `Account` controller decorated with an `[Authorize]` attribute?

Comment: The controller is, but I don't see how it relates to my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that LogOff has no actual page - it is just a server side method. So you should never redirect there from the Login method. You can fix that by changing the Login method to include a check to ensure that the LogOff method is never called inadvertently after the timeout expires.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {
            if (returnUrl != null && returnUrl.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("/account/logoff"))
            {
                return RedirectToLocal("/Account"); // Redirect to your default account page
            }
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }
```